# Not able to create ENUM type attribute using sequelize cli

Tags: orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Trying to create a model that has an enum field with certain values using Sequelize CLI.

```
sequelize model:generate --name user --attributes name:string,login_method:enum('email','google')
```

*Error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('*

**What is the right syntax to do so?**

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md

try

```
npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name user --attributes name:string,login_method:enum:'{email,google}'
```

Comment: @AkashElhance What message do you see when you run the command?

Comment: ERROR: Attribute 'Status_Name:enum:'{Completed,Pending}'' cannot be parsed: Unknown type ''{Completed,Pending}''

Comment: @AkashElhance I have tried 

```npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name user --attributes name:string,login_method:enum:'{email,google}',Status_Name:enum:'{Completed,Pending}'```

and I don't see error

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with

```
model:generate --name User --attributes 'login_method:enum:{google,facebook}'
```

Another good example is:

```
npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name devicelogs --attributes 'type:enum:{embedded,console,wearable,smarttv,browser,tablet,mobile}','browser:enum:{Chrome,Firefox,Safari,Opera,Internet Explorer,Edge,Edge Chromium,Yandex,Chromium,Mobile Safari,Samsung Browser}'
```

from sequelize-cli code you can also try

- first_name:string,last_name:string,bio:text,role:enum:{Admin, 'Guest User'},reviews:array:string
- 'first_name:string, last_name:string, bio:text, role:enum:{Admin, Guest User} reviews:array:string'

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create enum values from model:create command

you can do like this .

```
$ sequelize model:create --name User --attributes opts:enum(x,y,z)
```

hope this help .

Comment: @RAJKIRANSINGH is this helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

npx sequelize model:create --name User --attributes 'opts:enum:{x,y,z}'

Or

sequelize model:create --name User --attributes 'opts:enum:{x,y,z}'

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name User --attributes username:string,email:string,password:string,role:ENUM("users","admin")

instead or writing this try this

npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name User --attributes username:string,email:string,password:string,role:enum:'{users,admin}'